# Show that $-\int_\Omega\left(f^*(x)\partial_nf(x)+\partial_nf^*(x)f(x)\right)\text{d}x\le2\|f\|_{L_2(\Omega)}\|\nabla f\|_{L_2(\Omega)^n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be open such that it contains the support of $f$. I have encountered the following inequality

$$-\int_\Omega\left(f^*(x)\partial_nf(x)+\partial_nf^*(x)f(x)\right)\text{d}x\le2\|f\|_{L_2(\Omega)}\|\nabla f\|_{L_2(\Omega)^n},$$

where $\nabla f$ denotes the gradient of $f$ and $\partial_n f$ denotes the first derivative of $f$ with respect to the $n$-th coordinate. I believe that this should be simple enough to derive, but I am having difficulty doing so myself. I am not sure how to go from the expression on the left - which is close to the $L_1$- scenario to the $L_2$ - scenario on the right. One thought I had was to look at
$f(x)f^*(x)=|f(x)|^2$ and to argue that both $f(x)\le|f(x)|^2$ and $f^*(x)\le|f(x)|^2$, but I realise that this is nonsensical since both $f(x)$ and $f^*(x)$ might be complex, whilst the right hand since is always purely real.

How does one derive this bound? What am I missing?

Comment: Note that the integrand on the left hand side equals $\partial_n |f|^2$ and thus is also real. Also, $\|f\|_{L^2} = \|f^\ast\|_{L^2}$ and similarly for $\nabla f$. So this is just Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: So since the integrand on the LHS is real, I can apply Cauchy-Schwarz without needing the absolute value? What about the negative sign of the integral on the LHS?

Comment: $a \le |a|$ for any real $a$, no matter what the sign is.

Comment: Sure. I understand that the LHS is real, and so equivalently $-\int_\Omega f^*(x)\partial_nf(x)\text{d}x-\int_\Omega\partial_nf^*(x)f(x)\text{d}x$ is also real. But when applying Cauchy-Schwarz to each of these integrals separately, do I not need to treat each as if they might be, a-priori, complex? Does it necessarily follow that each term in the difference is real?

Comment: No. It's one integral over $\Omega$ with a real integrand. Don't write it as two integrals.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not see how I should apply Cauchy-Schwarz to this sum - what inner product is this equivalent to? If you want to post this as an answer, I will be happy to accept it - thanks for your patience so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is
$$
f^*(x)\partial_nf(x)+\partial_nf^*(x)f(x) = \partial_n |f(x)|^2
$$
and thus it is a real number. Therefore we can estimate
$$
-(f^*(x)\partial_nf(x)+\partial_nf^*(x)f(x)) \le |f^*(x)\partial_nf(x)+\partial_nf^*(x)f(x)| \le 2 |\partial_n f(x)||f(x)|
$$
since $|f| = |f^\ast|$ and $|\partial_n f| = |\partial_n f^\ast|$. By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
-\int_\Omega\left(f^*(x)\partial_nf(x)+\partial_nf^*(x)f(x)\right)\text{d}x\le 2 \int_\Omega|\partial_n f(x)||f(x)| \text{d}x \le  2\|f\|_{L_2(\Omega)}\|\partial_n f\|_{L_2(\Omega)}
$$
which implies the desired estimate.

Comment: Of course ... the triangle inequality is what I was missing. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: It's like looking for your glasses while they are on your nose